# How to run some code only once until Windows is restarted?

Tags: c#, windows

I am sure that someone else have asked such question before, but I didn't manage to find the answer, so I would really be thankful if anyone can help me.

I am working with some device which have rather strange driver. This driver crushes Windows when I try to initialize it more than once during one Windows session.
But the app could be closed and restarted many times during one session. So I have to somehow know if the driver has been already initialized.
Right now I am creating empty "ghost" process after driver initialization.
And anytime when the app is restarted, I'm checking if this process exists, and with this information I decide whether to initialize driver or not.

I think that my current way of handling such problem is really bad. 
Are there any other ways to handle it?

Comment: are you familiar with `Mutex` do a quick google search on how to create a single instance application. [Mutex](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you a little workaround that can let you achieve your goal without the need to undertake complex development tasks under a pure Matlab environment. The workaround implies the use of [system function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html). You didn't specify your operating system, so let's suppose you are under `Windows`.

Initialize your driver and save the initialization datetime somewhere (`mat` file in the application folder, binary file in the app data folder, registry key, etc... you have multiple choices and all of them are good) using the built-in `now` function.

Next time your application tries to initialize the driver, before proceeding, try to recover your last driver initialization datetime from registry, file or whatever you decided to use. If the information is not available, it means your application never run before so you can safely initialize your driver. Otherwise, you have to compare it to your last operating system boot time. Under `Windows` you can obtain this information as follows:

```
[status,cmdout] = system('wmic os get lastbootuptime');
```

If `status` is equal to `0`, the `cmdout` variable will contain something like this:

```
LastBootUpTime
20171201163757.330911+060
```

Parse that in order to retrieve the numeric part of the command output, which is a datetime value. Finally, compare your last initialization to your last boot time: if the former preceeds the latter, then you have to initialize your driver again.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I've consider that your solution is probably the best. Thank you, I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

First:
You said you "*I try to initialize it more than once*", that means you initialize it at least once. Why not add a registry key when you do initialization? Next time just check for the value of this registry key and accordingly take a decision of re-initializing it or not.

Second:
If Windows registry is not an option, there are other places like App Data folder, or your own app folder where you can have a SQLite db to store the state of initialization and take a decision accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am not sure about registry or database. Let's take for example registry. After windows restart registry flag wouldn't be reset to it's default value, so the app would think that initialization is already happen. Are there some kind of entities in windows, that returning their state to default after OS restart?

Comment: I think the second answer is what I need (I just should use Task Scheduler). Thank you for the answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether you are able to identify if the initialization has been carried out or not since the last reboot.  What does this driver do when it gets initialized?  Does it change a state somewhere that your application can evaluate?

If not, your application needs to set this state somewhere, e.g.:

- a running process, as you are doing now.
- a change in Windows registry.
- modification of a file on the hard drive.

Any non-volatile changes can be nullified at Windows startup using Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Task Scheduler is probably the thing that I was looking for.